# How do derivatives even work?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, learning

I'm a student currently looking into partial derivatives and was writing notes for a simple example.
$$\require{cancel}\text{find the derivative with respect to x:}\\x^2+xy-y^2=8$$ I got to the point where I was differentiating the $-y^2$ term, I wrote $\frac{d(-y^2)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$. This got me thinking, with my low level knowledge of what derivatives even are. Why does it not work out when I take out a factor of y and cancel terms like this $$-y\frac{\cancel{dy}}{\cancel{dy}}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Any knowledge and deep understanding is really appreciated!

Comment: You can't take out a factor of $y$ since $d(y^2) = (y + dy)^2 - y^2 = 2  y  \, dy + dy^2 = 2y \, dy$

Comment: Because $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$, and not $f(g)'$. I.e. you can't take a factor out of a derivative when that factor depends on the thing you're differentiating with respect to. Also, with the notation you're using, you're not doing partial derivatives - you're doing implicit differentiation, and that assumes that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Are you asking what is the correct method to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in this problem? Or if not, what are you asking? In general, if you want to know *whether* some alternate method works, you try it out on an example (such as this one), and you compare to the answer obtained from the correct method; if the answers don't match, then you know that the alternate method *does not work*.

Comment: $d(-y^2)/dy$ isn't $-y\cdot dy/dy$. It's close, but it's not quite right. As for what derivatives "really" are, there are a few different perspectives. Don't worry; your confusion with Leibniz notation is extremely common. Keep challenging and trying to understand how to prove calculus manipulations are valid, don't just push symbols around and hope for the best

Answer (score 2):

(This is more a comment than an answer, as it's asking for clarification, but it's too long for a comment.)

Is that the full text and context of an example that was assigned to you? Because I would describe that as "missing a boat-load of context".

See, there are (at least) two ways to view that formula.

1. Define $f(x,y) = x^2+ xy - y^2$. Differentiate $f$ w.r.t. $x$.

This version would use the notation for partial derivatives (which you mentioned), but that's $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, not $\frac{dy}{dx}$, which is what you've written. Although just what the "$=8$" would be doing in there in this case I'm not sure. And in this case, $\frac{\partial (y^2)}{\partial x}$ is actually equal to $0$, as $y$ doesn't depend on $x$!

2. Assume the equation $x^2+ xy - y^2 = 8$ defines $y$ implicitly in terms of $x$. Compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

In this version you would think of $y$ as a function of $x$, i.e. $y(x)$, and it should be clear that in this case you can't "factor $y$ out" anymore than your could, if, say, $g(x)$ were a function of $x$, write
$$\frac{d(g\cdot g)}{dx} = g\cdot \frac{d g}{dx}$$

Distinguishing between versions 1 and 2 depends on making clear whether we are in a situation where $x$ and $y$ can vary freely and independently, or one where a change in $x$ induces a change in $y$. The instruction "find the derivative with respect to $x$" does nothing to help us understand which of the situations we are in, and the use of the description "partial derivatives" and the notation $\frac{dy}{dx}$ point in completely opposite directions. This example needs more details and more context to be able to provide an answer.

Answer (score -3):

There's several important facts about derivatives that might help untangle the mess:

1. df/dx is *linear* operator.
2. f is not a function, but polynomial
3. to transform derivatives to your ordinary linear algebra, you just need to represent your polynomial in basis [1,x,x²,x³,x⁴,... ], and the coefficients need to be separable.
4. polynomial representation in matrix form is just:
   $$\begin{bmatrix}a& b& c& d& e\\f& g& h& i& j \\k &l &m& n& o\\p& q& r& s& t\\u& v &w &x &y\\ \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x²\\x³\\x⁴\end{bmatrix}$$
5. Derivative in matrix form is just(for size 5):
   \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0&0\\0&0&3&0&0\\0&0&0&4&0\end{bmatrix}

I.e. it's an identity matrix which has been "shifted" a little with coefficients correctly setup.

This uses the normal polynomial derivative calculation: $$f(x)=x^n \Rightarrow f'(x)=n x^{n-1}$$ and ability to move constants outside of derivative
$$f(x)=c g(x) \Rightarrow f'(x) = c g'(x)$$ and of course the sum rule
$$f(x)=g(x)+h(x) \Rightarrow f'(x)=g'(x)+h'(x)$$

6. To handle multiple variables like x and y, you might need to change the basis from [1,x,x²,x³,x⁴] to [1,y,y²,y³,y⁴]. Linear algebra has tons of information how the basis change can be done. Choosing correct basis for your derivative makes the derivative matrix look reasonable/easier to remember.
7. derivative matrix anyway only works if your calculations are in correct basis.

Comment: This nonanswer is at best helpful when studying linear algebra (not calculus). At worst it's just plain wrong. (2) is particularly confusing. "Separable" in (3) makes no sense.

Comment: separable means that if your matrix number slots a-y have $x$ in it, then the separable property does not hold, and this approach doesn't work. All x's need be inside the basis and not in the left side.